# What is the difference between comparing boolean value with boolean variable using = and ==?

Tags: c#, java, if-statement

Lets say if there is a boolean variable status. Assume status has value false.

I would like to know what is the difference between

```
if ( status = true )
{
   //block of code
}

if ( status == true )
{
   //block of code
}
```

I've tried to understand it by writing a sample program, the code in the first if block gets executed for whatever the value status is having (true or false).

For other primitive types, system throws compile time error if I use only one "=" in if and why it doesn't throw the error in case of boolean type. Thanks.

Comment: The first one is an assignment, you not comparing anything

Comment: The reason the code in the body of the `if` statement gets executed is that the result of the assignment is what's on the right, i.e. a `true`. The old value of `status` does not matter at all: it gets overwritten.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yeah, got it. if we are assigning false to status in if, then the code in the block is not getting executed. Thanks.

Comment: The first code block will ALWAYS be executed, what you say here is that: if status which I know is true is true do this, the other one checks if status is true then it continues

Comment: Yeah, we often forget that assignemtns are expressions that yield a result. Even if not very readable, we can write: `if(isPositive = x > 0) DoSomething();` which compares and assigns at the same time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first one is not a comparison, it is an assignment. The reason it compiles is that it assigns a boolean value, so the result of the assignment is also a boolean value.

The first statement assigns `status` a new value, and executes the `if` according to that new value (`true` in your case). The second statement compares the current value of `status` to the value on the right, and acts on the result of the comparison.

Note that is it never a good idea to compare `boolean` in Java or `bool` in C# to `true` or `false`: you can use `if (status)` instead of `if (status == true)` and `if (!status)` instead of `if (status == false)`. This, however, does not hold for *nullable* types in C#, so comparing `bool?` to `true` or `false` is often a good idea.

Comment: Also. The '=' will always execute because first you assigning it to true which will become **if(true)**

Comment: Comparisons like `if (status)` may seem strange at a first glance, but become much clearer with a good naming: `if (isDeviceEnabled)`. An even worse variant is `if (status == true) return true; else return false;` can be simplified `return status;`

Answer (score 10):

`if ( status = true )` will always be true, because you first assign `true` to `status`. On the other hand, `if ( status == true )` will only be true it `status` is true.

The best way to write it and avoid typos or confusion is:

```
if (status) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

At the first codepart you are assigning and not checking the value of status!
To avoid this errors you could write it like that:

```
if (status)
if (!status)
```

(this works only for booleans)

or

```
if ( true == status )

if ( "Peter" == name )
```

This swapping of the position of the var and string/value works for all variable types,
some coders use this to avoid typos with `=` and `==`,

because if you accidently write

```
if ( status = true )
```

instead of

```
if ( status == true )
```

This wouldnt work but wont give you a compiler error.(it would just set the var to true)

But if you are used to write

```
if ( true == status )
```

and you are making a typo and miss one of the equality signs the compiler will give a error.

or you could use equals:

```
if (name.equals("Peter"))
```

Comment: To compare Strings for equality, don't use ==. The == operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object. Use equals instead.

Comment: as long as the variables are strings and no objects this works fine...
but ill change it :D

Comment: @aphex: Not in C# (which is one of the tags of this question). There, `==` is perfectly fine for strings.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the "works for all variable types" statement.

Comment: `if ( true == status )` looks to me as someone would not trust the value of `true`.

Answer (score 3):

`if(status = true)`  will set status to `true`, then it sees `true`... this `if` will always be `true`.

`if(status == true)` is actually a check, this is what you want to use

Answer (score 2):

In java `if ( status = true )` is assignment, not comparision.

Comment: -1 it is not a compilation error. The return value of an assignement is the assignee, in this case `status`, which is a boolean and the code compiles fine. It would not if status were an `int` for example.

Comment: yes... i forgot about type... soryy.. ;)  NO probs for -1... :)

Answer (score 2):

First case is not comparing. Is just assinging `status` variable. And new `status` value will be returned. In this case is `true`.

See:

[= Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)
returns the operand value as result.

[== Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)
returns true if the values of its operands are equal or returns true if its two operands refer to the same object in case of reference type.

Answer (score 2):

In order to emphasize the difference between the two operators you could experiment with yoda conditions for a short while.

Yoda conditions are when you use the constant value as the first operand so your code will transform from: `if ( status = true )` to `if ( true = status )`. You cannot assign anything to the constant true so the compiler will give you a syntax error (preventing succesful compilation). Using a Yoda condition will force the compiler to give you a syntax error, rather than a warning.

I believe yoda conditions originate from unmanaged code and older compilers and don't serve a great deal of good in .NET languages but could be a fun way to learn the difference.

Comment: Yes, but why use yoda conditions if you can simply write `if(status)`?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I think Alex means in general. It's "unfortunate" that the example in question is a boolean variable.

Answer (score 1):

The First is for assignement, ***status = true*** and the second is for comparision ***status == true***.

Answer (score 0):

explaination of

```
If (Status = true){ 
// code execution
}
```

and

```
If (Status == true){ 
// code execution
}
```

---

If you try to check if 2 values equal to each other, you use

```
value1 == value
```

If you try to assign a value to another variable, you use

```
value1 == value
```

---

> So what does "If (value = value){}" do ?

To explain this you Need to know, that Java checks, if a variable can be defined.
If it is possible Java does.

So if you write a code like

```
If (Status = true){
System.out.println("Variable Status successfully changed!");
} else {
System.out.println();
}
```

it will try to assign the value "true" to the variable Status, then return if succeded.
IF it succeded the condition will be entered and "Variable Status successfully changed!" will be printed to console.

THEORETICALLY

But since Java requires a boolean as condition it won't function.